# how to use setInterval with redux-thunk?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, setinterval, redux-thunk

I'm using redux-thunk to manage async functions, and I want to use setInterval within an action creator, this is my code:

```
export const startLobbyPolling = () => dispatch => {
  const pollTimer = setInterval(() => {
    dispatch(fetchLobby);
  }, POLL_TIME);
  dispatch({ type: START_LOBBY_POLLING, payload: pollTimer });
};
```

`fetchLobby` is another action creator that simply fetch a request and store its data.
but surprisingly it's not working as it only shows `START_LOBBY_POLLING` action in redux debugger tool and nothing happens afterward. I would appreciate it to know how to use setInterval with redux.

Comment: What's `POLL_TIME` value?

Comment: it's a constant value of 5000

Comment: What;s in that `fetchLobby` function?

Comment: ```export const fetchLobby = () => async dispatch => {
  const response = await tortuga.get('/lobby/my-lobby');
  const data = response.data;
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_LOBBY, payload: data });
};```

Comment: also tortuga is axios instance with a baseURL no other config

Comment: it's seems like it's not related to `setInterval`, i dispatch `fetchLobby` alone in `startLobbyPolling` but the action won't fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like i should had called the function not just pass it as an argument to dispatch
    `dispatch(fetchLobby);` -->
 `dispatch(fetchLobby());` and it works now

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to not use redux as a polling manager.

Instead you should have a component / container that does that for you. The reason being is, that when the component will get unmounted, also your polling will be properly canceled

```
const PollContainer = ({ fetchLoby, children }) => {
   useEffect(() => {
      const ptr = setInterval(fetchLoby, POLL_TIME)
      return () => clearInterval(ptr)
   }, [fetchLoby])

   return children
}
```

you can now use your PollContainer and as long as it is mounted, it will keep fetchLoby.

Comment: Thanks this seems like a better way and i was unaware of it

Comment: Thought this was helpful, but edit queue is full.  https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing particular about using `setInterval` with `redux-thunk`. It should work just as it would anywhere else. You need to see the callback function which has been used in the `setInterval`.

Comment: that does not answer the question, as it seems that he wants to be polling, which makes sense to use setInterval...

Comment: Yup, I kinda missed out on reading the variable name. Updating now.